# Is there an AutoLISP code to automatically label hatch layers in AutoCAD?

Tags: autolisp

**Autolisp to Write Each Hatch Layer Name **
Shortly I want an AutoLISP to Find the name of each hatch I Select in Autocad and Automatically write its layer name on the Hatch with Suitable Text height
Thanks

I Tried to ask Chat Gpt , its keeps Generates codes that don't do anything
and gets errors such as
; error: ActiveX Server returned the error: unknown name: AddText